# How to publish Next.js app as npm package?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js, publish

I have a web app built on Next.js. I want to publish this app as npm package so it can be used in other projects.
I tried to find resources and help using google but did not find any useful information.

Is it possible? if yes how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: The NPM website does have decent documentation on it.

Comment: I know how to publish a npm package developed using plain JavasSript and also with React Js components. But I can't figure out how can I achieve this for Next.js. @Quentin

Comment: Why would it be different for Next.js?

Comment: Most of the resources explains only how to generate npm package of React components but not the complete web application. Same goes for Next.js @Quentin

Comment: Have you found the solution to this question?
How to publish the Next.js app as an npm package?

Answer (score 5):

I have almost the same need. I created a blog using next js pages and i want to share these pages for 2 next js projects.

**Until now**, i've been able to make it using vite / rollup builder this way (simplified):

###### NPM package:

```
// node_modules/@namespace/next-blog/pages/ssr/BlogArticle.tsx
export SSRBlogArticle = getServerSideProps(...) {...}
export BlogArticlePage: NextPage = (SSRProps) => <Blog {..props} />
```

###### Using Package in my main next js app

```
// ./src/pages/blog.tsx
import { SSRBlogArticle, BlogArticlePage } from '@namespace/next-blog'

export getServerSideProps = SSRBlogArticle

const BlogPage: NextPageWithLayout = BlogArticlePage

// some layout
BlogPage.getLayout = (page) => <Layout>{page}</Layout>

export default BlogPage
```

> The problem is about the usage of `process.ENV` and `useRouter`. `next/link` seems not to work...

###### Here is my vite configuration file :

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts'
import gql from 'vite-plugin-simple-gql'
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'
import * as path from 'path'
import pkg from './package.json'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    tsconfigPaths(),
    gql(),
    dts({
      insertTypesEntry: true,
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: [{ find: '@', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') }],
  },
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
      name: 'NextBlog',
      formats: ['es', 'cjs'],
      fileName: (format) => `index.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [
        ...Object.keys(pkg.dependencies),
        ...Object.keys(pkg.peerDependencies),
      ],
    },
  },
})
```

##### So i would like to add more questions to the original one :

- Can we **read env file from npm packages?** process.ENV reading main app env file ?
- Why useRouter is not working properly?
- Am i doing it right? Is it **good practice?**

Thanks for your help :)

#### Edit

###### Process.env

- I've managed to find out why all `process.env` were removed from build, **vitejs** removes them and replace with `{}`. Solution is :

```
define: {
  // keep process.env* vars in code bundle
  'process.env': 'process.env',
},
```

###### useRouter

Still impossible to understand the issue with it...

Here one example error on useRouter in main app when clicking on next/link:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'push')
    at linkClicked (index.es.js?4bcb:3731:1)
    at onClick (index.es.js?4bcb:3830:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js?ac89:4161:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js?ac89:4210:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js?ac89:4274:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js?ac89:4288:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js?ac89:9038:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js?ac89:9070:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js?ac89:9083:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js?ac89:9094:1)
    at eval (react-dom.development.js?ac89:9285:1)
    at batchedUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js?ac89:26096:1)
    at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js?ac89:3988:1)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js?ac89:9284:1)
    at dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay (react-dom.development.js?ac89:6462:1)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js?ac89:6454:1)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js?ac89:6427:1)
```

For now, the only work around i'm thinking off is using native a tags...

#### Edit 2

I have finally found out the solution : to make router object not null inside of my package, i have to pass it from main nextjs app to page's package. Inside of the package, i had to wrap my components with `RouterContext`:

```
// package next page
import { RouterContext } from 'next/dist/shared/lib/router-context' // next 12

const MyPackagePage = (props) => {
  <RouterContext.Provider value={props.router}>
    <MyComponents ... />
  </RouterContext.Provider>
}

// main next app
const Page = (props) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  return MyPackagePage({ router, ...props })
}
```

Now works fine. Less easy to integrate and more boilerplate code, but at least it's possible de export next pages in npm packages.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `semantic-release` npm package.

In your `package.json` file you should add follow configuration

```
  "release": {
    "branches": [
      "master"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
      "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
      [
        "@semantic-release/changelog",
        {
          "changelogFile": "CHANGELOG.md"
        }
      ],
      "@semantic-release/npm",
      "@semantic-release/github",
      [
        "@semantic-release/git",
        {
          "assets": [
            "CHANGELOG.md",
            "package.json",
            "package-lock.json"
          ]
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

And your project should be public and should have `"private": false` in `package.json`.