# create reusable package from component in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js

I have a Next.js website where I've created a component named TestMe.tsx. This component uses Next.js Link and Image components, and my project is using Next.js version 14.1.0 . I want to generate a build of this component so that I can reuse it in other Next.js projects as an Npm package.

I prefer to configure the next.config.mjs file to achieve this. How can I set up my next.config.mjs file to build TestMe.tsx as a standalone package that can be published on npm and easily reused in other Next.js projects?

I tried the following configuration but it didn't work:

```
const nextConfig = {
  webpack(config, { isServer }) {
    if (!isServer) {
      config.externals.push("/src/components/TestMe/index.tsx");
      config.output.library = "TestMe";
      config.output.libraryTarget = "umd";
      config.output.publicPath = "auto";
    }

    return config;
  },
  experimental: {
    externalDir: true,
  },
};

export default nextConfig;
```

please help me! thanks.

Comment: I think this post would help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72458804/how-to-publish-next-js-app-as-npm-package

Comment: thanks but I prefer to configure the next.config.mjs file to achieve this. they used vite and rollup!

Comment: also they used page directory but i use app directory in next.js